# React Native Router Flux automatically pops back to previous screen

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I am using `react native router flux` in my app. I have three screens. First is Splash, Second is Mobile Number and third is OTP. When user enters mobile number successfully I am redirecting the user from Mobile Number Screen to OTP Screen, but after few seconds the OTP Screen automatically moves to Mobile Number Screen. Following is my Router code

```
const RouterComponent = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Scene key="root" hideNavBar>
        <Scene key="splash" component={SplashScreen} hideNavBar initial />
        <Scene key="mobileLoginScreen" component={MobileLoginScreen} />
        <Scene key="otpLoginScreen" component={OTPLoginScreen} />
      </Scene>

    </Router>
  );
};
```

Following is the code when I get success for entering correct mobile Number and moving to OTP Screen

```
const loginUserSuccess = (dispatch, response) => {
  dispatch({
    type: MOBILE_NUMBER_LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS,
    payload: response
  });

  if (response.data.status === 1) {
    Actions.otpLoginScreen();
    // console.log(response.data.msg);
  } else {
    // console.log(response.data.msg);
    loginUserFail(dispatch, response.data.msg);
  }
};
```

I don't understand why the OTP Screen automatically pops back to Mobile Number Screen?

My Splash Screen code is as follows

```
class SplashScreen extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    setInterval(() => {
      Actions.replace("mobileLoginScreen");
      // Actions.mobileLoginScreen();
    }, 4000);
  }
```

Following is my OTP Screen Code

```
class OTPLoginScreen extends Component {
render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>OTP Screen</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

}
```

Full Code can be found at https://github.com/pritish12/reactreduxdemo

Comment: Can you post code for OTP Component?

Comment: @SHG21 Please have a look

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the implementation of react-native-router-flux but I assume that your SplashScreen gets mounted a 2nd time after transition to the OTP screen, which triggers the `componentDidMount` method of SplashScreen and therefore starts the interval to launch the mobile screen. You can set a break point or a `console.log(..)` within the componentDidMount method to investigate further